# Graphql-dotnet, not able to connect to React application

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, graphql-dotnet

Currently I am working on GraphQl-dotnet, i was able to create graphql server, now i want to connect the server to my front end, React Application, I tried with Apollo i could not do it can any one help me on it .

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gokhan-gokalp.com/en/introduction-to-graphql-and-designing-simple-query-api-with-aspnet-core-2-0/

- setup graphql endpoints in your dotnet web api application & call those end points inside your React application.